# Long running HTTP task & callback in Android

Tags: android, http, callback

I have a requirement in my Android app, that makes an HTTP request to the server to perform a long running task. The architecture on the server is that; the HTTP request returns immediately with a transaction ID. What I need next is to poll the server to check whether the job has completed and once completed show the result to the user.

When the first HTTP task completes I show a UI *Fragment* which has a progress bar asking the user to wait while the task completes. Ideally, I would like to show the result to the user on the same *Fragment* once the task has been done. But I would also need to consider situations where the user might press the Home button or move out of the app/screen in some way.

My current solution is:

1. Poll every 10-15s with some sort of exponential backoff, as long as
   the activity is still attached.
2. The server sends a push notification regarding task completion - but
   I'm worried about reliability of this.

Is there a better way to achieve this? If so, what would be a good design pattern for this? Are there any libraries available that handles this scenario?

Comment: why are you worried about the push notification

Comment: If you are considering battery conservation, opening socket(UDP/TCP) connection would be better than polling. Making a single HTTP request at intervals consumes lot of battery. By the way, push notification is just another socket connection.

Comment: @PramodYadav I have found delays happening, and ideally would like to avoid that.

Comment: @vakman Websockets is something I'm considering now. Thanks.